# Outlook Mobile Service Configuration Issue

Tags: mobile, outlook, sms

I am working on writing a OMS implementation.  I have verified that service is compliant with the service and schema definitions.

When trying to set up the account in Outlook 2007 to test the service, it allows me to use an **https** address, but not an **http** address.

According to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb277363.aspx) "The URL of the OMS Web service can be either http or https, but it is https if not otherwise specified"

I have not been able to find any doucmentation that would explain why Outlook will not even let me try to do anything in the wizard if the service url does not start with https.

The error that it returns when a **http** address is entered is:

> The web service address is incorrect or corrupted. Check the web service address or contact your administrator

I have also tried creating a temporary cert on my local machine to test the service, but outlook is rejecting the cert because it is not valid.

Is there any way to test the service or run it over http?

Comment: are you wating to see the paylod of the traffic? as fiddler can decode https traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone in seeing this error, we've also come across this issue, one of the 3! comments on the msdn documentation also reports an issue with using http (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/community/history/bb277363.aspx?id=2)

Apart from exposing your service as https there doesn't seem to be a way around this :(

Answer (score 0):

> Connection Security
>
> To protect the information as it is
>   transferred over the Internet, OMS Web
>   services are required to support SSL
>   (Secure Socket Layer) encryption. SSL
>   can be used to establish more secure
>   connections on untrusted networks,
>   such as the Internet. SSL enables
>   encryption and decryption of messages
>   exchanged between client and server,
>   thereby helping to protect messages
>   from being read during transfer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb277361(v=office.12).aspx#OfficeOutlook2007OMSMobileServicesGuidelinesPt1_CommunicationProtocols